# (Docker) Getting error: docker-php-source: no such file or directory when building docker file

Tags: php, docker, build

When I'm trying to build the docker file at: https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/3f43309a0d5a427f54dc885e0812068ee767c03e/7.1/Dockerfile

command: `docker build -t php_image .`

I'm encontering the following error:

```
Step 14 : COPY docker-php-source /usr/local/bin/
lstat docker-php-source: no such file or directory
```

Could anybody help me to figure out something wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: make sure `docker-php-source` still exist on your directory

Comment: At the beginning, I also though the way and downloaded that file , then rebuilt the docker file. I still got the error for the next command since the docker-php-source can't be extract!!!

Answer (score 4):

You don't have the proper context of the docker build.

Just **clone** the repo to be sure to have all the files (and its right permissions):

```
git clone https://github.com/docker-library/php
docker build . -t php_image
```

But if you need to customize that image, it's easier to make your own Dockerfile based on the official build:

```
FROM php:7
RUN #your commands 
RUN ...
```