# Docker PHP image. lstat docker-php-source: no such file or directory

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to setup PHP 5.6.30 fp, but i got error.
Error the same as here [(Docker) Getting error: docker-php-source: no such file or directory when building docker file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514720/docker-getting-error-docker-php-source-no-such-file-or-directory-when-buildi)

But i can`t understand how to resolve this.
my folder looks like

app
   --docker
      --workspace

inside workspace Dockerfile i paste all from https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/eadc27f12cfec58e270f8e37cd1b4ae9abcbb4eb/5.6/fpm/Dockerfile

`Step 15/22 : COPY docker-php-source /usr/local/bin/
ERROR: Service 'workspace' failed to build: lstat docker-php-source: no such file or directory`

So what i must to do? 
i did this command docker pull php before and it is not helped.

So i have this .yml file

`version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build: ./docker/app
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    command: "true"
  workspace:
    build: ./docker/workspace
    volumes_from:
      - app
    links:
      - php
      - nginx
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - app
  nginx:
    build: ./docker/nginx
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - php
    volumes_from:
      - app
  php:
    build: ./docker/php
    expose:
      - "9000"
    volumes_from:
      - app
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes_from:
      - app
    expose:
      - "3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
  memcached:
    image: memcached
    ports:
       - "11211:11211"`

inside workspace/Dockerfile i have all strings from github image 6.6.30fpm
Then inside this folder i do 
docker-compose build workspace

Before this in workspace i had another settings

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN \
  sed -i 's/# \(.*multiverse$\)/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y upgrade && \
  apt-get install -y build-essential && \
  apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
  apt-get install -y byobu curl git htop man unzip vim wget nano locate

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing --allow-unauthenticated
RUN apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated libmcrypt-dev libxml2-dev mysql-client
RUN apt-get update -y --allow-unauthenticated && apt-get upgrade -y --allow-unauthenticated && apt-get install -q -y php5 php5-dev php5-fpm php5-mysqlnd php5-mcrypt

RUN echo "extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so" > /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini \
    && ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini  
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php  
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

and this works but i want to 5.6.30 instead of 5.5.9

Comment: Are you sure that [all these files](https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/5.6/fpm) exist?

Comment: what you mean? 
which files? 
i am just starting work with docker and i read docs and Getting Starting with docker. So it is all new for me. 
I thought this images like package.json. Copy, paste and npm install :)) But this is different

Comment: should i need to pull all images from git clone https://github.com/docker-library/php and then try again? but it is stupid to pull all images if i need one

Comment: So please describe step by step, how did you try to start php-fpm :)

Comment: @spil i did this in desc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it is due to the fact that there is no permission to execute.
Try

```
chmod +x docker-php-*
```

**UPD:**
Just put [all these files](https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/5.6/jessie/fpm) inside directory with your php 5.6 Dockerfile

If you want to use php 7.2 version, [this link is for you](https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/7.2/stretch/fpm)

Anyway for other googlers. Just explore [this repository](https://github.com/docker-library/php) and you will find that you want. :)

Comment: chmod: cannot access 'docker-php-*': No such file or directory

Comment: yes it works, thanks.
But now i have problems with mysql. As i understood this php image installed mysql also and my bash looking in to this mysql instead of mysql in .yml file with my settings but this is different story :)

Comment: The link is dead :( Did you mean these files? https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/7.2/stretch/fpm

Comment: @DBX12 You're right, but your link is for php 7.2 version. Updated the answer

Comment: Well, that's because I needed the link for 7.2 and time was running out to edit the commend ^^